# How to make news downloaded every 30 minutes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever, feedzirra

I have two models Company and News
How to make news downloaded every 30 minutes?
I've tried through gem 'whenever', nothing happens

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :load_news 

  def load_news
    last_entry = self.news.last
    if last_entry.nil?
      feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(self.url)
    else
      feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(self.url,
        :if_modified_since => last_entry.published_at.to_time)
    end

    Company.add_entries(feed.entries, self.id)
  end

  def self.update_all_feeds(urls)
    Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(urls,
      :on_success => lambda { |url, feed|
        rss = Comapny.select("companies.id").where(:url => url).first
        Company.add_entries(feed.entries, rss.id)
      }
    )
  end

end

class News < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :guid, :name, :published_at, :summary, :url, :company_id
end
```

Comment: With a class named News, I hope you have something in your initializer to avoid having a singular news item referred to as 'new'. That's just begging to conflict with ruby's 'new' method. I would rename this to NewsItem or some such. Other than that, what exactly does your whenever config look like? Does the job appear among your cron jobs? For fetching in the background every 30 minutes, that's not a bad way to do it.

Comment: I dont have experience with whatever. But i'll use delayed_job or sidekick for time sheduled things.

Comment: @sockmonk `every 1.hours do
  runner "Company.load_news"
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever scpript

```
every 15.minutes do
  rake "collect"
end
```

and rake file

```
task :collect => :environment do
  urls = Company.select("companies.url").all.map { |v| v[:url] }
  Company.update_all_feeds(urls)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your whenever script is going to call `Company.load_news`, then that method needs to be a class method and not an instance method:

```
def self.load_news
```

or

```
def Company.load_news
```

Whatever your command, always try running it in the rails console the same way it appears in your whenever script, to debug it. Also check your rails log when the script fires, it should show any errors assuming that your whenever jobs successfully made it into cron.